# $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\arctan(n)/n$ converges or diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Try ration test but fail.

I have no idea about that.

I know that $0<\arctan n < \pi/2$

but $(\pi/2)/n$ is divergent.

I try on wolframalpha and it say the series is conditionally converge

How can I prove that?

Comment: Are you sure you entered it into WolframAlpha correctly? That series does not converge at all. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+arctan%28n%29%2Fn+from+n+%3D+1+to+infinity

Comment: $\arctan n \ge \arctan 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series diverges by the Comparison Test: The $n$-th term is greater than $\frac{1}{n}$ if $n\ge 2$.